# What is the effect of movies and TV series on criminals?

Tags: behavior, criminology

In whole genres of movies and TV series, criminals and criminal organizations have a central role, either in the role of villains or anti-heroes. And I think it is safe to assume that, given the broad dissemination of these media, real-life criminals do watch them as well, at least casually.

My question then is: are there any studies evaluating the effect of media about or featuring criminals on real-life criminals? Does watching these media change the inclinations of criminals, maybe towards more stereotyped behaviors?